# Как удалить тег и достать текст

Tags: javascript, jquery

Делаю поиск, но столкнулся с проблемой, что скрипт не работает, если текст взят в тег `span`. Как можно удалить `span`, чтобы текст остался?

html:

```
<p>какой то текст <span> здесь </span> находиться</p>
```

Результат должен быть таким:

```
<p>какой то текст  здесь находиться</p>
```

Comment: какой именно скрипт не работает?

Comment: Лучше добавь разметку и скрипт ибо ты можешь решать совсем не ту проблему, которую надо решать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без `jQuery` можно так:

```js
function removeSpan() {
  var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0]; // берем элемент p
  var textInside = elem.textContent; // сохраним текст из p
  var child = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0]; // берем элемент span
  elem.removeChild(child); // удалим span из p
  elem.textContent = textInside; // перезапишем текст в p
}
```

```html
<p>Какой то текст<span> здесь </span>находится</p>
<button onclick="removeSpan()">Удалить span</button>
```

Для случая, когда элемент `p` и `span` всего один - будет работать. В противном случае можно добавить к элементам `id` и вместо [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) вызывать [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

Answer (score 1):

Простой вариант:

```js
$('p').html( $('p').text() );
```

```css
p {color: red}
span {color: blue}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>какой то текст <span> здесь </span> находиться</p>
```

Если у вас много тегов и вам нужно достать только с одного, то можно таким воспользоваться:

```js
$('.b').replaceWith(function() {
  return $(this).text();
});
```

```css
p {color: red}
span {color: blue}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>какой <span class="a">то</span> текст <span class="b"> здесь </span> находиться</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Для удаления лишнего тега можете попробовать так:

```js
var str = "<p>какой-то текст <span>здесь</span> находится</p>";
var searchText = $(str).text();
console.log(searchText );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: подозреваю под _удалить span_ имелось ввиду убрать сам тег, а текст, который был внутри оставить, а не удалить полностью элемент

Comment: @Grundy, да возможно )) поставлю в ответ второй вариант, спс

Comment: я нашел вот такой код но проблема в том что слова сливаются, нет пробелов var wrap = $(".sub-scroll .text").find("[data-key]");
                                    var wrapText = wrap.text();
                                    wrap.replaceWith("" + wrapText + "");

Comment: @DimaVleskov а чем вас не устраивает мой ответ или ответ других участников? данные ответы же решают вашу проблему в вопросе? или  ваш вопрос не полный?